# How can I sync a Reference Manager database with a Bibus database or other Linux reference management database?

Tags: linux, debian

I am attempting to finally shuck off my last interactions with Windows. Everything is rolling along nicely (I only need the dual boot once a week), but one sticking point I've had is that I must be able to use references stored in a [Reference Manager](http://www.refman.com/) database, which is used by other Windows users. I know that Bibus can import RIS documents, but has anyone developed a way to sync a Linux reference management database with the .rmd files. I will probably do this if the answer is no, but I'd rather use someone else's stuff, if it exists.

I believe the question boils down to: **Is there any software for Linux that opens Reference Manager Databases?**

BTW I'm using (Debian Squeeze) and Windows >= XP.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

JabRef also should be able to import RIS files, maybe that addresses your issue?

Comment: Nah, I am somewhat indifferent to which management sys I run on Linux,  but Bibus seems especially well suited given its similarity to Reference Manager. I have tried JabRef and it is definitely good software, so thanks for the mention.